# Detect if view is scrolled out of the screen

Tags: android, scrollview

I have layout with scrollView as below :

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

              <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/transparentLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
              </LinearLayout>

              ... other views

</ScrollView>
```

I want to detect if the transparentLayout (**LinearLayout**) is scrolled out of the screen.

Comment: use `View#setOnScrollChangeListener`

Comment: @pskink Ok i have tried using that, i can get X and Y position but how will i  get to know if the view is out of the screen

Comment: see `getLocationOnScreen`

Answer (score 13):

I solved it in this fashion:

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {

                Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
                scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
                if (layout.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                    // if layout even a single pixel, is within the visible area do something

                } else {
                    // if layout goes out or scrolled out of the visible area do something

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: scroll view - appear in the screen works, but out of screen does not, because it shows all my table cells at once that have disappeared from screen..